# Cannot catch file creation with strace

Tags: linux, files, strace

When I run the following `make` command in a build directory it's almost empty (file in question is absolutely certainly not there)

`strace -f -e trace=execve,vfork,open,creat -s 1024 make <target>`

After it finishes, the file is totally there. So it must have been created by `make` or one of its child processes (or children of their children and so on).

However when I grep the `strace` log for either the name of the file or for `creat` I cannot find the system call responsible for creation of this file.

What am I missing? Are there other system calls I should be monitoring?

---

**EDIT:**

It turns out the mistake was in both my strace comamnd and my grepping.
All the answers were helpful, thank you, everyone, for your time.

I actually failed to communicate that the file was in a subdir and I was grepping using the name of a file along with the subdir's name. But since strace does not provide info on current working directory this approach didn't work so well (I ended up stracing `chdir` and `rename` calls to get the desired effect).

So PaulHaldane's first suggestion was right and to the point. As well as larsks's answer in which he has actually guessed how the file got created.

Comment: Have you tried using `-e trace=file`? That should pick up anything that acts on a file name.

Comment: There are scenarios you might never be able to detect with `strace`.  One of them: `ln -s foo bar; strace -ologs touch bar; grep foo logs`.

Comment: @PaulHaldane, I haven't. Trying it now...

Comment: @PaulHaldane, nope, didn't help.

Comment: @SatoKatsura, wow. Can you explain why this happens?

Comment: You're tracing functions in user space, while the target of a symlink is created in kernel space.

Comment: Shouldn't they be able to see the execve though?

Comment: You should be able to get it with `-f -e trace=file`.

Comment: @SatoKatsura, thank you for the elaboration. Although apparently it is not the case with my example here I find it very educational and will keep in mind next time I'm using strace.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run strace without the `-e` option and see if that improves your result.

There are a number of ways to create a file.  Instead of `open`-ing it, it is highly likely that whatever tool produces that file first opens a temporary file, writes the data, and then renames the file on completion.

With your current limit (`execve,vfork,open,creat`) you're not going to see that sort of behavior.

For example, given this simple python script:

```
import os
import tempfile

fd = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(dir='.', delete=False)
fd.write('this is a test\n')
fd.close()

os.rename(fd.name, 'output')
```

Running `strace` with your arguments and then looking for `output` in the results yields nothing:

```
$ strace -e trace=execve,vfork,open,creat -o trace -f -s 80 python tmptest.py
$ grep output trace
$
```

But if I remove the `-e` filter:

```
$ strace  -o trace -f -s 80 python tmptest.py
$ grep output trace
4523  rename("/home/lars/tmp/tmpZDwvPK", "output") = 0
```

In the comments on your question, Sato Katsura provides an example in which you will not see your target filename in the `strace` output, but I think you are unlikely to encounter that when running `make` as long as you start with a clean build environment.

Comment: Using `-e trace=file` rather than an explicit list of syscalls gets round this problem (it certainly picks up the `rename` call in the test program). I'm puzzled that it didn't work for the original problem with `make`.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is [`sysdig`](https://sysdig.com/blog/sysdig-vs-dtrace-vs-strace-a-technical-discussion/), with e.g. a command something like:

```
sysdig -p '%proc.pname[%proc.ppid]: %proc.name -> %evt.type(%evt.args)' \
  evt.args contains /tmp/yourbuilddir
```

running in one terminal, then with the temporary file [rename code](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::AtomicWrite) of:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use File::AtomicWrite;
File::AtomicWrite->write_file(
    {   file   => "/tmp/yourbuilddir/foofile",
        input  => \"blah",
        MKPATH => 1
    }
);
```

executed and then the `sysdig` running back in the other terminal should reveal something like:

```
bash[13645]: perl -> stat(res=-2(ENOENT) path=/tmp/yourbuilddir )
bash[13645]: perl -> stat(res=-2(ENOENT) path=/tmp/yourbuilddir )
bash[13645]: perl -> mkdir(path=/tmp/yourbuilddir mode=0 )
bash[13645]: perl -> stat(res=0 path=/tmp/yourbuilddir )
bash[13645]: perl -> stat(res=0 path=/tmp/yourbuilddir/ )
bash[13645]: perl -> stat(res=0 path=/tmp/yourbuilddir/ )
bash[13645]: perl -> open(fd=3(<f>/tmp/yourbuilddir/.tmp.8XUnHhOrIn) name=/tmp/yourbuilddir/.tmp.8XUnHhOrIn flags=39(O_EXCL|O_CREAT|O_RDWR) mode=0 )
bash[13645]: perl -> ioctl(fd=3(<f>/tmp/yourbuilddir/.tmp.8XUnHhOrIn) request=5401 argument=7FFEF6BE5020 )
bash[13645]: perl -> lseek(fd=3(<f>/tmp/yourbuilddir/.tmp.8XUnHhOrIn) offset=0 whence=1(SEEK_CUR) )
bash[13645]: perl -> fstat(fd=3(<f>/tmp/yourbuilddir/.tmp.8XUnHhOrIn) )
bash[13645]: perl -> fcntl(fd=3(<f>/tmp/yourbuilddir/.tmp.8XUnHhOrIn) cmd=3(F_SETFD) )
bash[13645]: perl -> write(fd=3(<f>/tmp/yourbuilddir/.tmp.8XUnHhOrIn) size=4 )
sshd[678]: sshd -> read(res=970 data=bash[13645]: perl -> stat(res=-2(ENOENT) path=/tmp/yourbuilddir )..bash[13645]:  )
bash[13645]: perl -> close(fd=3(<f>/tmp/yourbuilddir/.tmp.8XUnHhOrIn) )
bash[13645]: perl -> rename(res=0 oldpath=/tmp/yourbuilddir/.tmp.8XUnHhOrIn newpath=/tmp/yourbuilddir/foofile )
sshd[678]: sshd -> read(res=186 data=bash[13645]: perl -> close(fd=3(<f>/tmp/yourbuilddir/.tmp.8XUnHhOrIn) )..bash[13 )
```